# how to parse a file that is changed continuously using awk?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk

for example if we have a file contains :

```
Hello world
Hello earth
Hi everybody
```

we can easily parse it to get the first and second columns of the lines contains the word `Hello` using `awk`:

```
awk '/Hello/ { print $1 }' file
awk '/Hello/ { print $2 }' file
```

What if the content of the file is changed:

```
Hello world
Hello earth
Hi everybody
Hello sky
Hi madame
Hello USA
```

How can we parse only the new entries added to this file (using `awk`):

```
Hello sky
Hi madame
Hello USA
```

without re-parsing the already parsed Information?

```
Hello world
Hello earth
Hi everybody
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use two files:

```
if [ -e checkfile ]; then
  lines=$(wc -l <checkfile)
else
  lines=0
fi
# read all new lines from source file and append them to target file
sed -n $((lines+1)),\$p file >>checkfile
awk '...' checkfile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the file's contents via `tail -f` (or `tail -F`) e.g.

```
tail -f file | awk '...'
```

From the `tail` man page:

```
   -f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
          output appended data as the file grows; -f, --follow, and --fol‐
          low=descriptor are equivalent
```